# Finding the file that is being loaded on the fly in joomla

Tags: joomla

im using a joomla template in my localhost. I would like to edit one of the on-screen module's position. i used chrome and firefox to inspect the elements and even changed the properties. it works the way i want, but the problem is, im not sure where these actual files are residing in my localhost. There are 100s of files and its frustrating there isn't an easy way to find out the exact file that i have to edit.

I understand that joomla contents are generated on the fly and thus it isn't easy to find the exact file. I have also seen some of the past related questions in stackoverflow.com, asked by desperate users like myself, nothing works.

Im hoping someone knows of a tool or a trick that can help me. I even tried indexing the localhost folder (c:\wamp\www\demo) to search file contents, it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of the module is almost certainly determined only by the css in your template. Using web inspector in Firefox or Chrome you can see which file (and the file path) of any styles that are currently being applied to the module, so you can simply modify the rules in that files.

Answer (score 0):

I love Mac
Since my files are in the localhost, i have been trying to search for the div class that is generated on the fly, but my pc couldn't thoroughly search the contents of the file.
On my mac, i searched for the div class word and hey! it showed me a list of files that contained the div class and i found the file in a matter of seconds! how cool is that!!

Thanks Guys, hope this helps someone too!